# SQL Server 2005 - Select Performance - WHERE and NULL

Tags: sql, performance, t-sql, sql-server-2005, database-performance

I have the following issue:

SQL Server 2005

- Table: Documents
- Records: 400'000
- Field Value IS NOT an INDEX
- Query:

  ```
  SELECT * FROM Documents WHERE value = 0
  ```

CASE A:

- ALL 400'000 Records have value = NULL
- Performance = X Seconds

CASE B:

- 200'000 Records have value = NULL
- 200'000 Records have value <> NULL
- Performance = X + Y Seconds

CASE C:

- 400'000 Records have value <> NULL
- Performance = X + Y + Z Seconds

Is this a common behavior, or do I have to search the cause of the performance degrees somewhere else ?

Comment: Run `SET STATISTICS IO ON;SET STATISTICS TIME ON;` and post the output of that for the cases rather than letters of the alphabet.

Comment: It's a bit difficult to do it, cause it's a production database I have can't access. Let's say that the performance decreased by a 30%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost certainly don't have an index on the `value` column.  Given this assumption, your results aren't very surprising.  `NULL` is internally stored as a separate bit that is simpler to lookup (and reject) than performing a numeric comparison.

If you had an index, then I'd be somewhat suprised by these results.  It would also help if you posted exact figures about the table (column widths), as well as exactly what results you saw instead of "X, Y and Z".  And as always, when checking for performance issues *look at the query plan*.